# SQL maximum average of grouped items

Tags: mysql, sql

Modelling on line shop where users can buy items and rate items they have purchased. There are four tables

Buys(user, item)

User(UserID, name)

Rates(item, rating)

Item(ItemID, Description,price)

I want to return each user with a list of items they have not bought that have the highest average rating.

The code I have built so far is a bit clunky but seems to do half the job:

```
SELECT U.UserID, U.name, I.ItemID, I.Description, AVG(R.Rating) AS avgRate
FROM Item I, User U, Rates R 
WHERE R.Item=I.ItemID 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT Item  FROM Buys B  WHERE I.ItemID = B.item and U.UserID = B.user) 
group by U.UserID, item,I.ItemID Order by U.UserID, avgRate DESC
```

Which is giving me the following output:

```
UserID   name   ItemID  Decription           avgRate
1        Jones   5      Computing Textbook   5
1        Jones   11     Tennis Ball          3.5
1        Jones   12     Tennis Raquet        4
2        Brown   5      Computing Textbook   5
2        Brown   11     Tennis Ball          3.5
2        Brown   12     Tennis Raquet        4
```

But I want by output to only select one item per user so:

```
UserID  name    ItemID  Decription           avgRate
1       Jones   5       Computing Textbook   5
2       Brown   5       Computing Textbook   5
```

Ive tried limiting the ordering but it only then give me 1 row, and you cant use the MAX() function with AVG...

Comment: Your tags are incompatible

Comment: When asking DBMS questions like this one, it's best to use just one tag for dbms tech. That is, don't use mysql and sql-server together. That's because different DBMS systems have different languages and performance characteristics. Which is it? MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks, im using MYSQL workbench, didnt quite realise they were different

Comment: Does the avgRate ever come out as the same highest average value for two products for the same user and if so what is then the criterion for selecting which row to ultimately show for that user or would you show two rows for that user in that instance?

Answer (score 0):

Presupposing it never comes out as the same highest average value for two products for the same user you might use:

```
with cte1 (UserID,name,ItemID,Decription,avgRate)
as
(
SELECT U.UserID, U.name, I.ItemID, I.Description, AVG(R.Rating) AS avgRate
FROM Item I, User U, Rates R 
WHERE R.Item=I.ItemID 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT Item  FROM Buys B  WHERE I.ItemID = B.item and U.UserID = B.user) 
group by U.UserID, item,I.ItemID Order by U.UserID, avgRate DESC
)
,
cte2 (UserID,name,ItemID,Decription,avgRate,rank1) as
(
select * , rank() over (partition by name order by avgrate)from cte1
)
select UserID,name,ItemID,Decription,avgRate from cte2 where rank1 in
(
select max(rank1) from cte2 group by userid
) 
order by userid
```